# Reset pose to reset velocities

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If I were to tinker in the file reset_pose.py and add lines about resetting other states than just the positions, could I also zero out the velocities of the joint states?  For example, when I move the waist joint to rotate the robot, it sways around due to the controller being underdamped.  If I just hit 'reset pose', the robot might snap back to a certain position, but it won't have zero velocity at the joints.  But if I published additional commands in the reset, I could take that out, right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/675/reset-pose-to-reset-velocities/) by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sorry I am unclear what you are trying to achieve here.

But in general, [reset_pose.py](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/8e072fa972a0e2cd0104a35de1ecf1870f5c6c01/ros/atlas_utils/scripts/reset_pose.py?at=default) only works with [atlas_position_controllers.launch](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/8e072fa972a0/ros/atlas_utils/launch/atlas_position_controllers.launch?at=default) by setting controllers desired joint positions.  Once the published commands are received by individual position controllers, each controller will actuate the joints towards desired position.

The `Reset Model Poses` button in the GUI simply [resets the Model pose](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d50d145f8639646720c5c1738bc74b0645614e18/gazebo/physics/Entity.cc?at=default#cl-517), and leaves model joint configuration untouched, the model is "teleported" to its starting pose, but the dynamic properties (linear and angular velocities of the links) are unchanged.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0